# Is Google Voice susceptible to hacking like regular MMS or Whatsapp messages?

Tags: security, sms, malware, mms, google-voice

I have been using Google voice in a public facing way so as to reduce the chance of receiving malware messages over SMS/MMS or Whatsapp.

But is it just as susceptible for someone to be able to sneak something in over a GVoice MMS or SMS?

I am worried because I received a photo from an unsolicited phone. Is there a chance that having clicked on that photo (which just enlarged  and presented information about itself)  compromised my phone? For context:

- [95% of Android phones can be hacked with one just MMS | Kaspersky official blog](https://www.kaspersky.com/blog/critical-android-mms-vulnerability/9471/)
- [Jeff Bezos phone hacking explained: What you need to know for your own security](https://www.cnn.com/2020/01/22/tech/bezos-phone-hack-explainer/index.html)

Comment: When it comes to attacks via MMS I would expect from my mobile network provider to have some "virus scanner" running filtering out all MMS that have this malicious pattern. If that is the case the "persons" able to attack are intelligence or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Google Voice, aka Hangouts, is fully encrypted point to point.  If you've posted anywhere with your Gmail account, you could have a message pushed to you.  Unless you have OS 6-10 you'll need an "anti-spam" app HIYA is a very good one. The newer OS have been given the ability to flag calls & SMS - MSMs as spam.
Good luck.

Comment: Hi - thank you for this explanation. To confirm, if let's say someone is sending out malware to random phones over MMS, and my GV happens to be one of them, GV would prevent a malicious MMS from being received (especially when using the GVoice app on my phone).